# if array match an array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

> $search = array(5,8,9);

and a database table like this :

```
id | name   | cat
-------------------------------
1  | name1  | 1,2,3
2  | name2  | 5,8,17,25
3  | name3  | 14,21,5,19
```

and I have to search for ($search) in my (cat) database table.
I tried `in` and `FIND_N_SET` but unfortunately they doesn't support array search.

Is there is a way to do it without PHP, just in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` comparison operator works like an equality operator. This:

```
cat IN ('5','8', '9')
```

is equivalent to:

```
( cat = '5' AND cat = '8' AND cat = '9')
```

OR you can use also `REGEXP`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
cat REGEXP '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]' AND cat REGEXP '[[:<:]]8[[:>:]]' AND cat REGEXP '[[:<:]]9[[:>:]]'
```

There one more option you can use `FIND_IN_SET` to find single id

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('5', cat)
    AND FIND_IN_SET('8', cat)
    AND FIND_IN_SET('9', cat)
```

Comment: @Bahad001, you can try last 2 options `REGEXP` or `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: thanks man it work i did an foreach like this :
`foreach($genreExclude as $exc){
   $where .= ' AND FIND_IN_SET("'.$exc.'",MANGA_GENRES)<=0 ';
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You would do it like this:

```
select *
from table t
where find_in_set(5, cat) > 0 and
      find_in_set(8, cat) > 0 and
      find_in_set(9, cat) > 0;
```

It is unclear whether you intend for `and` or `or` in the query, though.